# What's the difference between \[.......................\] and \begin{math}.............\end{math}?

Tags: math-mode

It seem like a same thing to me. But I don't ever try \begin{math}.............\end{math}

Comment: Please provide a little more details since at the moment for me it is not entirely clear what you are asking.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. Also for me it is not clear.

Comment: Are you asking difference between `\[ .... \]` and `\begin{math}....\end{math}`? As others have mentioned your question does not make much sense as it is

Comment: They are not the same thing. `\[....\]` makes displayed math. `\begin{math} XXX \end{math}` gives the same as `$ XXX $`. I have never seen anyone use the `math` env in my 20+ years of LaTeX

Answer (score 9):

A quick experiment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \verb@\[\sum_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\]@:
  \[\sum_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\]
\item \verb@\begin{displaymath}\sum_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\end{displaymath}@:
  \begin{displaymath}\sum_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\end{displaymath}
\item \verb@\(\sum_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\)@:
  \(\sum_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\)
\item \verb@\begin{math}\sum_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\end{math}@:
\begin{math}\sum_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\end{math}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And of course, `$...$` is the same as the last two.  And (with `amsmath`) `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}` is the same as the first two.

Comment: And [`\[...\]` is preferable to `$$...$$`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/107497).